# Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x16dac960, Perl interpreter: 0x16a9c010 Bugzilla Installation

Tags: linux, perl, bugzilla

Hi I am trying to install bugzilla in my dedicated server with perl version 5.8.8. After installing necessary modules.

```
I tried to install "DBD-Pg" module via "perl install-module.pl DBD-Pg" command.
```

When I ran the above command I am getting the following error

```
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x16dac960, Perl interpreter: 0x16a9c010 
at /server_path/support/httpdocs/Bugzilla/Install/Util.pm line 20.
```

Afterwards I try install other modules, but the result is same. How can I resolve this issue. I cannot uninstall perl, because if I do that it will impact my production site. I have zero knowledge on perl. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this "install-module.pl" before.

Usually you'd use either CPAN or the packages from your OS to install perl modules.

Debian systems (like ubuntu) can do

```
apt-get install libdbd-pg-perl
```

Red-hat systems (like centos and suse) should be

```
yum install perl-DBD-Pg
```

Or simply use "CPAN".

```
cpan -i DBD::Pg
```

Comment: Looks like install-module.pl is some kind of convenience wrapper in Bugzilla which installs pre-requisite modules. The error it gives is very strange though - normally you will only get that through a faulty XS module.

Comment: How can we overcome it? When we tried with cpan install,we are getting the following error
make: *** [dbdimp.o] Error 1
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK

Comment: Did you try the built in OS packages (eg. using yum or apt)?